# Why we need to create a socket in any programming language?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

For example in python language :

```
 sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

why we need to define that?

And why `socket.AF_INET` equals to 2 or `socket.SOCK_STREAM` equals to 1 ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here?  Are you asking why we need to create an object of a class or what the class's parameters mean?

Comment: Sockets must be defined in order to interact with the low level networking interfaces in a device.

Comment: The "why" question is easy to answer: There is a standard (RFC 793 and others) that says so.

Comment: @KlausD. I can't understand that terms. Am i need to start from 0 in network programming ?

Comment: To do network programming it is a good idea to have a basic knowledge of the IP protocol (IPv4 and IPv6), TCP and maybe UDP.

Answer (score 2):

A socket is a file-like interface to the TCP-IP stack of a computer. It's the Unix philosophy applied to the network stack.

`socket.AF_INET` & `socket.SOCK_STREAM` are just enums that determine the type of socket. Their values are passed directly to the C-API IIRC.

More info: https://www.quora.com/What-is-socket-programming-a-socket-server-and-a-socket-client